# Get-ADUser is not using import text file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, pipeline

I'm using a text file generated from AD of disabled users names, e.g. jdoakes. I am using the following script to obtain the last time the user logged in. When ran, it is only returning non-disabled user. Any way to make this work?

```
Get-Content oldusers.txt |
  Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Name,Manager,LastLogon |
  Select-Object Name, Manager,
    @{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

It doesn't return any of the user names in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `-Filter` with `-Identity` (identity is the parameter you're binding to when you pipe). You'll have to filter after the fact:

```
Get-Content oldusers.txt | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties Name,Manager,LastLogon | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $_.Enabled
    } | 
    Select-Object Name,Manager,@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

Comment: Use `-not $_.Enabled` if you want to filter for disabled accounts.

Comment: The above code with the -not worked for me except for one problem. It shows that the last time the user logged on was December 31, 1600. Should I be using a different property?

Comment: I changed the script to this and the dates came out correctly: Get-Content oldusers.txt | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties Name,Manager,LastLogonTimeStamp | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript {
         -not $_.Enabled
    } | 
    Select-Object Name,Manager,@{n='LastLogonTimeStamp';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}}

Comment: Both of you helped me figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: @user88671 note that you should [understand the difference between lastLogon and lastLogonTimestamp](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/07/lastlogon-vs-lastlogontimestamp.html) and use the one that's appropriate for you. I recommend the latter unless you need the latest data, because using the former requires additional code to scan all domain controllers.